# How do I correctly send an int to the UART Buffer on a pic32?

Tags: c, uart, pic, spi

I am receiving strange results on my pic32 and I am not clear what have I did wrong.

Using a logic analyzer I have confirmed that the slave is replying with 0xA3. I also did a test with an LED to see if `"test == 0xA3"` and the result was true.

ut when I run this code I get **0x3F** in my serial terminal (configured to display as hex):

```
csLow();
spiWrite(0xFF);
csHigh();
Delayms(10);
char test = SPI1BUF;
U1TXREG = test;
//sprintf(str, "%X", test);
//UART1_Tx(str);
```

However when I convert the int to a string using sprintf and transfer to the UART buffer it prints "A3" which is what I would expect.

I also tried this:

```
U1TXREG = test & 0xFF;
Delayms(1);
U1TXREG = (test >> 4) & 0xFF;
Delayms(1);
U1TXREG = (test << 4) & 0xFF;
```

The output is "3F 0A 30"

I also tried:

```
U1TXREG = 0xA3;
U1TXREG = 0xA0;
U1TXREG = 0x03;
U1TXREG = 0xFF;
```

My terminal displays:

```
3F 3F 03 3F.
```

Comment: Looks like a baudrate problem.  Try either halving the baudrate on PIC or doubling the baudrate on your terminal receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue is the terminal program I was using.  I swapped from the terminal program created by Microchip, "USB_Serial_Terminal_v0_02", to realterm.  Realterm saved the day.

Comment: Note also that 'protocols' that depend on time delays are unreliable on many systems:(